# How do I split my QML code into multiple files?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols

I have just started playing with QML and have a view where I have a bunch of components as follows:

```
Window {
    ....
    property Component dateTumbler: ControlView {
        // Definition follows
    }

    property Component timeTumbler: ControlView {
       // More definition follows
    }

    // More controls
}
```

This makes the main QML file very long and cumbersome to edit and maintain. I tried to separate this into different files as follows:

```
// DateTumblerView.qml
component: DateTumblerView { // Not sure how to inherit here..
    // Definition here
}
```

I'm trying to use it like this:

```
property component dateTumbler: DateTumblerView {}
```

However, this never works and the `DateTumblerView` is never found. I am not sure if I am doing this correctly.

[EDIT]
ControlView is defined as follows:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtMultimedia 5.5

Rectangle {
    id: view
    property bool darkBackground: false

    Text {
        id: textSingleton
    }

    SoundEffect {
        id: playCalSound
        source: "qrc:/sound/test.wav"
    }
}
```

[END EDIT]

**What is the proper way to split QML code into multiple files?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `DateTumblerView.qml` file should look like this:

```
ControlView {
   // More definition follows
}
```

And you would use it like this:

```
property Component dateTumbler: DateTumblerView {}
```

Or:

```
Component {
    id: dateTumbler

    DateTumblerView {}
}
```

Or if you wanted to use it directly:

```
DateTumblerView {}
```

It's pretty much the same as when your code was just in one file. Anytime you do `<Type> {}`, you're inheriting that type and can set or add new properties, functions, and subcomponents. The difference is that it is in a separate file, has a specific name (the name of the file), and you can reuse that code as many times as you want.

For more details, see [Defining Custom QML Types for Re-use](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmlfirststeps.html#defining-custom-qml-types-for-re-use).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried doing that and it complains that ControlView is not a type. I am adding the definition of ControlView to my original post

Comment: Disregard my last comment...that happened because I cannot spell. need my first coffee...